# java factory pattern issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, factory-pattern

I am using selenium webdriver for testing and want to give the opportunity to select which browser to run each set of tests in. I have used a factory to achieve this but for some reason I can't seem to get it working. Here is what I have

```
class WebDriverFactory {

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

private WebDriverFactory() {
}

public static void setChromePath() {
// Set file path here 
}

public static void setIEPath() {
// Set file path here 
}

public static WebDriver getWebDriver(String type) {

System.out.println("choose a browser:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.next();

if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
  return createChrome();
} else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
  return createFirefox();
} else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
  return createInternetExplorer();
} else {
  return null;
}


}

private static WebDriver createChrome() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files          

(x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver_win32_2.1/chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary",    

"C:/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
 return driver;
}

private static WebDriver createFirefox() {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
return driver;
}

private static WebDriver createInternetExplorer() {

File file = new File("C:/Utils/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.33.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
return driver;
}
}
```

And in the test class I have:

```
String type = null;
WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(type);
```

When I enter a string the scanner doesn't seem to do anything and the browser doesn't open? Could anyone help me out?

I now have this in the test class:

```
System.out.println("choose a browser:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String type = scan.next();
WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(type);
```

Comment: calling getWebDriver(null) should get you an NPE? You may put constant string  first in comparison

Comment: Doesn't do anything still it seems to be getting stuck after I hit enter with my string choice.

Answer (score 0):

As Jayan mentioned, you should have got a NPE since you are passing null to the `getWebDriver` method. However, keeping that aside, in your code, you are reading a string using `scan.next()` statement, but you haven't assigned the read value to the variable `type`.

Saying that, your statement should be as below:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
type = scan.next();
```

Apart from that, I don't see any use of passing `type` variable to the `getWebDriver` method, as you are anyhow, taking the input from user for `type` in `getWebDriver` method.

Comment: So is it a problem in the getWebDriver method?

Answer (score 0):

You should first correct the method `getWebDriver(type)` so it doesn't return null always! And then see where you go. As Mubin suggested, you could let go of the input parameter `type` if you are going to read the input inside the method. However, Based on the discussion in comments to this answer here's how the method `getWebDriver(type)` should look like:

```
public static WebDriver getWebDriver(String type) {

  if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
    return createChrome();
  } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
    return createFirefox();
  } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
    return createInternetExplorer();
  } else {
    return null;
  }

}
```

OP was passing null to this method in the test implementation, and also not assigning the value read by `Scanner`. It isn't clear what the OP was expecting. As Jayan mentioned, we should get an `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Well I originally had the scanner in the test class would it be better there?

Comment: @user2177781 Since it is a kind of factory method, I think it's best if you read input in the test class and pass it to the `getWebDriver(String type)` method; also, make sure you're not passing null.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it uniform. It will help you to use the debugger in your IDE, or using print statements to see what you're passing and what's being returned from the method.

Comment: yeah I have been it gets to the scanner you enter a string then it just doesn't go anywhere

Comment: Does it enter the `getWebDriver()` method?

Comment: @zEro: Although the edit to OP code is well-intentioned, it made it difficult to figure out whether or not to approve the edit (I did, I the end). It would have been better IMO as an extra edit to your own answer.

Comment: That is exactly how I had the method isn't it?

Comment: @user2177781 I've removed the scanning code from the `getWebDriver()` in my answer. I think we've come to a dead end.. and unless you debug a little further and provide us with more information we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I had already done that and like I said it gets to the scan.next() line and wont go any further

Comment: @user2177781 Oh dear! Did you try `scan.nextLine()`?